# i can not close my form

Tags: javascript, html

i have a form for save information into database. some input in this form should be required by required attribute.
i want to have a close button for close and reset form into this form. i defined a function for 'onclick' in this button for close form,but this is not work because i have required element in this form.
how can i fix this problem?

```
<form name="save" method="get" action="saveform.php" id="formpoi" style="visibility: hidden">
    <button id="clos" onclick="winclose()"></button><br />
Name of place:<input type="text" name="place" class="f" required="true"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/> 
    </form>
```

and this is javascript function:

```
function winclose(){
    var form=document.getElementById('formpoi');
    form.close();

 }
```

Comment: Since when does a HTML `form` element have a `close` method …?

Comment: its called a reset method not close.. `form.reset()`

Comment: Please clarify whether you're using the word "close" to mean "reset the form to its initial state". Note that `<button>` elements will be `type="submit"` by default, so if you want your button to function as a reset button make it `type="reset"`; if you want it to do nothing but call a JS function then make it `type="button"`.

Comment: i use form.reset() but i get an error that say i have to fill required input

Comment: i want addition to reset form close that so.

Comment: _"i get an error that say i have to fill required input "_ - See my previous comment about the `type` attribute on your button. Currently you have a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

```
function winclose(){
    //var form=document.getElementById('formpoi');
    // http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp
    window.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that what you mean by "close" is that this form is in a popup window, and that you are actually trying to do two separate things:

1. reset the form back to its original state (clear out any answers in inputs)
2. close the pop-up window this form is inside

So first lose that `<button>`.

Next, add a new input like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="winClose()" value="Close">
```

And your javascript function:

```
function winClose() {
    var form = document.getElementById('formpoi');
    form.reset();
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: _"a `<button>` inside a form will submit the form"_ - Not if you set `type="button"`. And speaking of `type="button"`, did you intend the input element you suggest to have that too?

Comment: i set type="button" but form isn't close by winclose()

Comment: Can you please clarify where the form is? Popup window? Iframe?

Comment: this is into div element

Comment: i can solve this problem by hide form again with calling winclose.  var form=document.getElementById('formpoi');
      form.reset();
      form.style.visibility='hidden';